# Port install dsniff fails

Tags: macports

I am having trouble installing `dsniff` with Macports.

```
$ sudo port install dsniff
[....]
--->  Configuring dsniff
Error: Failed to configure dsniff, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_net_dsniff/dsniff/work/dsniff-2.4/config.log
Error: Failed to configure dsniff: configure failure: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_net_dsniff/dsniff/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
Error: Processing of port dsniff failed
```

---

Log from: `/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_net_dsniff/dsniff/main.log`

```
:info:configure checking for ether_ntoa... yes
:info:configure checking for Berkeley DB with 1.85 compatibility... configure: error: Berkeley DB with 1.85 compatibility not found
:info:configure Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_net_dsniff/dsniff/work/dsniff-2.4" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --mandir=/opt/local/share/man 
:info:configure Exit code: 1
```

---

macOS Catalina

Comment: what version of MacPorts are you running.

Comment: @jmh Version: 2.6.2

Comment: That looks like an error with the port file best to ask on macports issues.

Comment: Nearest issue seems https://trac.macports.org/ticket/59559